# How to request a url from the browser

Tags: java, python, url, browser

I would like to receive the address of the site of the active tab in the browser from my application (in Python or Java)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! State precisely: a) What is your question b) What you are tried so far (show a **Minimal Complete Verifiable Example**) c) Where are you getting stuck (again show code).

Answer (score 0):

look into a library called selenium you are going to need a headless web browser  too.